# parse server migration cannot connect to mongo

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform

This is related to migration to parse server from `api.parse.com`.

- On windows server, installed mongo db and nodeJS.
- Installed Python.
- Installed Parse Server.
- Getting following error messages.

StyleChat is the name of the app.

http://localhost:1337/stylechat

> parse-server-example running on port 1337. info: Parse LiveQuery
>   Server starts running warn: Unable to ensure uniqueness for usernames:
>   Error: read ECONNRESET
>       at exports._errnoException (util.js:1036:11)
>       at TCP.onread (net.js:564:26) warn: Unable to ensure uniqueness for user email addresses:  Error: read ECONNRESET
>       at exports._errnoException (util.js:1036:11)
>       at TCP.onread (net.js:564:26) (node:252160) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection
>   (rejection id: 4): MongoError: read ECONNRESET (node:252160)
>   UnhandledPromiseRej

Comment: Add your code for connecting to mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

if you run nodejs on window, you should use iisnode to run nodejs on iis.
i found this [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JUYCDnqR8p0)

have fun.